MobaXterm - Create SSH tunnel on mysql socket
Is it possible to create an ssh tunnel on a socket that starts automatically? In the event of an interruption, it should be automatically rebuilt.
I've tried a few things but always failed. maybe you have a solution for me?
SSH Tunnel CMD:
ssh -N -L 5001:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock USER@IP
thx
